# c# - how to get user access token without login from facebook?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I want to get user access token(Graph API Explorer) from facebook without login

I tried with app access token but I am unable to get comments for the posts

Code is for app access token:

```
        string appId = "APP_Id";
        string appSecret = "APP_Secret";
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = appId,
            client_secret = appSecret,
            grant_type = "client_credentials"
        });
        fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
        var accessToken = fb.AccessToken;
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? because i am looking for something similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of the FacebookClient with the Users AccessToken to get info about the User!

I think here is no way you get the Token without calling the FB.Login

From the API Documentation:

> **User Access Token** – The user token is the most commonly used type of token. This kind of access token is needed any time the app calls
>   an API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on
>   their behalf. User access tokens are *generally obtained via a login*
>   dialog and require a person to permit your app to obtain one.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,Can I get comments for the posts using App access token